# CSS selector exclusions in Selenium

Tags: java, html, css, selenium

I'm trying to grab all `article` elements on the page whose class begins with `news-feed-item` and exclude the ones that end in `is-headline`.

I'm using this selector to grab all the elements on a page in Selenium.
Currently it is failing each time, not finding the element on the page. Am I doing something wrong in my selector?

Below is my implementation in JSON format:

```
"newsItems":{
    "SimpleName": "News Item",
    "ALL":{
        "selectorType": "cssSelector",
        "selector": "#news-feed article[class^='news-feed-item']:not([class$='is-headline'])"
    },
```

Comment: Don't know about selenium but on plain CSS your selector works https://jsfiddle.net/3gnttr2q/1/

Comment: Can you add html piece?

Comment: Few examples would help, maybe there is another way.

Comment: Please read [ask]. Please provide the code you have tried and the execution result including any error messages, etc. Also provide a link to the page and/or the relevant HTML.